# Numerical functional derivative of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-derivative

I can solve the following differential equation,

\begin{align}
     i\frac{d b_1(t)}{dt} &= \alpha b_1(t) + \beta_1 \left[E_g(t)\right] b_2(t)\notag \\
     &+ \beta_2 \left[E_p(t)\right] b_2(t)\\
     i\frac{d b_2(t)}{dt} &= \alpha_2 b_2(t) + \beta_3 \left[E_g^*(t)\right] b_1(t) \notag \\
     &+ \beta_4\left[E_p^*(t)\right] b_1(t)
\end{align}

where $E_g(t)$ and $E_p(t)$ are some complex functions of t. This differential equation can be solved numerically to find the functional dependence of $b_1(t)$ and $b_2(t)$. Then, I did,
$$P(t) = b_2(t)b_1^*(t)$$
I want to numerically find,
\begin{equation}
\left. \frac{\partial P(t)}{\partial E_g(t)}\right\vert_{E_g=0,E_p=0}
\end{equation}
Can someone suggest an algorithm to implement it?